# Документация по MS RDP Control C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, rdp, doc

Не могу найти документацию по компоненту microsoft RDP control, хотелось бы изучить и понять как пользоваться этим.

Comment: [Это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/termserv/remote-desktop-activex-control)?

Comment: Не совсем, в ней я не нашел как взаимодействать с этим элементом на C#, или он только на С++?

Comment: Это ActiveX контрол, на каком вам надо языке, на том с ним и работайте. C# тоже умеет с ActiveX работать, но не будут же авторы примеры для всех языков писать, вам это придется самому разбирать